# Video Thumbnail with Paperclip+ImageMagick+Heroku

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, paperclip, rmagick

I am trying to take snapshots of uploaded videos.
The following Paperclip processor works fine in my local environment, but fails in Heroku.

```
module Paperclip
   class VideoThumbnail < Processor

  require 'RMagick'
   attr_accessor :current_geometry, :target_geometry, :format, :whiny, :convert_options, :source_file_options

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @file                = file
      @format_op              = options[:format]
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end


    def make  
      src = @file
      dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, ".png"])
      dst.binmode
      parameters = []
      parameters << "-quiet"
      parameters << ":source"
      parameters << ":dest"
      parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")

      success = Paperclip.run("convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(file.path)}[1]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))

      dst
    end
  end
end
```

The error is the following:

```
2013-04-17T18:25:20.781972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/admin/content_items host=mclauncher.herokuapp.com fwd="186.55.107.205" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12253ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-04-17T18:25:20.774386+00:00 app[web.1]: convert: Delegate failed `"ffmpeg" -v -1 -vframes %S -i "%i" -vcodec pam -an -f rawvideo -y "%u.pam" 2> "%Z"' @ delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1060.
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-17T18:25:20.774386+00:00 app[web.1]: convert: missing an image filename `/tmp/Valves20130417-2-170vly120130417-2-78zghs.png' @ convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2838.
2013-04-17T18:25:20.774386+00:00 app[web.1]: convert: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-XXqompcz.pam': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480.
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-17T18:25:20.780154+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Admin::ContentItemsController#create as HTML
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/paperclip_processors/video_thumbnail.rb:47:in `make'
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-04-17T18:25:20.780154+00:00 app[web.1]: Command :: convert -quiet '/tmp/Valves20130417-2-170vly1.mp4[1]' '/tmp/Valves20130417-2-170vly120130417-2-78zghs.png'
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: Cocaine::ExitStatusError (Command 'convert -quiet '/tmp/Valves20130417-2-170vly1.mp4[1]' '/tmp/Valves20130417-2-170vly120130417-2-78zghs.png'' returned 1. Expected 0
2013-04-17T18:25:20.779544+00:00 app[web.1]: Here is the command output:
2013-04-17T18:25:20.780154+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F5Y3tflzqvUlDbaOPBDiYHwUTGIVpoMaUIXL/QQfkbg=", "content_item"=>{"content_group_id"=>"3", "name"=>"asd", "emailable"=>"", "app_launch_url"=>"", "app_install_url"=>"", "file_item"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000061d2878 @original_filename="Valves.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"content_item[file_item]\"; filename=\"Valves.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130417-2-1wvc61m>>}, "commit"=>"Create Content item"}
```

Any help?

Comment: What version of `RMagick` are you using? Could it be that you are using a heroku with only 1 dyno, which means you are limited in space, so new images simply can't be allocated on heroku disk?

Comment: RMagick 2.12.0. I was using 1 dyno. I tried 2 dynos and got the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but It looks like heroku has a read-only disk storage. Take a look at [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem). Instead, uploading using S3 is a preffered way of storing files. They have an [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) on the subject as well.

Comment: As you can see in your link. There are two directories that are writeable: ./tmp and ./log. It is using /tmp